# Retain image in a Image View

Tags: android

I'm making an app where a user sets his profile picture in an Image view and the clicks on a button which saves the profile picture on a sd card. I want that if the user closes the app and opens it up after sometime, his profile picture should be shown in the image view.

Can anyone help me with the code on how I can retain the profile picture until it is updated again by the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by.

Save the image path to SharedPreferences (storage for your app that is kept even if the application is closed)

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

When the application is reopened restore the image path value from SharedPreferences

Set the ImageView using the restored value

[Set Imageview to show image in sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224710/set-imageview-to-show-image-in-sdcard)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have more options hot to do that

1. use preferences to save the path to the picture at the SDcard
2. use database

just thing a little bit how can you do this

you can see this question for more help

[Saving image file path to sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479429/saving-image-file-path-to-sqlite-database)

[How to save image path using Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357646/how-to-save-image-path-using-shared-preferences)